Deserialize a list of a class coming from Kafka in Flink
I have this class that does deserialization for messages that come from Kafka into Flink. I am trying to implement another class or update this class to also deserialize data that comes in, which is in the format of a list of a specific class. I have no idea how to proceed as I have tried doing it using typereference, but this ultimately gave me serialization problems.
public class GenericDeserializer<T> implements KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    private final Class<T> type;
    
    public GenericDeserializer(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    private static final String TAG = "GenericDeserializer";

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<T> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void deserialize(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord, Collector collector) throws IOException {
        if (collector == null) {
            System.out.println("Collector is null. UNABLE TO PROCEED. FLINK ERROR?");
            return;
        }

        if (consumerRecord == null) {
            System.out.println("consumer record is null. Ignoring");
            return;
        }

        if (consumerRecord.key() != null) {
            System.out.println("key=" + consumerRecord.key() + " - " + consumerRecord.key().getClass().getName());
        }

        if (consumerRecord.value() != null) {
            if (!(consumerRecord.value() instanceof byte[])) {
                return;
            }

            byte[] b = (byte[]) consumerRecord.value();
            //System.out.println("value=" + new String(b) + " - " + consumerRecord.value().getClass().getName());

            T raw = om.readValue(b, type);
            if (raw == null) {
                System.out.println("Error deserializing. Orig: " + new String(b));
                return;
            }
            collector.collect(raw);
        } else {
            System.out.println("value is null");
        }
    }

}


what's the serialization problems?

org.apache.flink.client.program.programinvocationexception:%20The%20main%20method%20caused%20an%20error%3A%20Error%20in%20serialization.
This is the error, I assume it is because one of the classes I use does not implement serializable. But I can’t find any other classes that do the same.
